# Still X commits ahead of upstream after pull request merge

Tags: git, github

I've viewed numerous answers to questions very similar on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to resolve the problem. I made a bunch of changes and have a humongous commit history, which i'm ok with for now. I did a pull request once everything was working and the pull request was merged with the repo I forked from. But my fork is still X number of commits ahead of the original repo, and I can't seem to reset this commit counter. I've tried rebasing, resetting, and seemingly everything else I can find. But I still see this:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uMOG.png)

How do I get everything back into alignment? I've only used git for my own projects up to this point, and some of git's design is confusing me.

Comment: Take a look at http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://blog.zenika.com/2017/01/24/pull-request-demystifie/ to try to understand the triangular workflow.

Comment: Hi zigarn, I read that link and I never had a separate branch from master to make edits to, thinking I could just do a pull request from that same branch. But the pull request was successful, and I don't see why github doesn't update the status of my fork as being in-line with the original repository. git status seems to say that everything is fine when I run it, but github thinks otherwise. http://i.imgur.com/eOYxmJj.png

Comment: Please provide the results of `git fetch --all`, `git branch -vv` and `git log --graph --oneline --decorate master origin/master upstream/master`

Comment: Here are the results. http://i.imgur.com/gea9U3B.png

Comment: Which pull request is it supposed to be? 11, 12 or 13? From what I can see your fork's branch isn't merged in the upstream/master branch.

Comment: I guess 13. That branch i'm no-longer making changes to since this has proven complicated. I've been making commits from new branches and leaving the master branch alone. I just want the master back in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PR [AreaFiftyLAN/toornament-client#13](https://github.com/AreaFiftyLAN/toornament-client/pull/13) was merged but not with a classic merge but a squashed merge in commit [0d1b439](https://github.com/AreaFiftyLAN/toornament-client/commit/0d1b439424d98e1bc7a08bc58217778d5f477215) and from commits I don't see in your history.

By using a squashed merge, there is no track in the upstream history of the merge from your fork's branch. This way, your fork cannot be fast-forwarded to the upstream's branches...
The only way is to get rid yourself of your fork's branch once it's considered merged.

To force your fork's `master` branch to be at the same point of the upstream's `master` branch:

```
git fetch --all
git push --force upstream/master:master
```

Once you do that, it may complain about you local master branch being ahead/behind. If you do a `git pull [--rebase]`, you will just merge/rebase your local history with the upstream's one and you'l still stay ahead. So you can move your local `master` branch to your fork's `master` branch:

```
git stash # in case of local modifications
git reset --hard origin/master
git stash pop
```

This way you should be back in sync with upstream and fork repositories.

---

You should also think about cleaning your remotes to only keep those 2 (origin and upstream) as I guess other ones are just local duplicates of them.
You can check the URL of your remotes with `git remote --verbose`: just keep one for each different URL.

Answer (score 9):

An alternate solution to equalize fork master and upstream master.

```
git checkout master              // --> will move to origin master
git fetch upstream               // --> pulls all branches from mainline/remote master
git reset --hard upstream/master // ==> reset your origin local code with latest remote master 
git push --force                 // ==> update with remote with your local updates
```

Comment: this works easily as compared to the other solution

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem. git cannot find upstream...

```
% git fetch upstream 
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I deleted my repo and forked again.

Comment: did that solve the problem? or not?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34859917)